# Maximum allowed PHP-Postgres prepared statements?

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

Is there a limit on the number of prepared statements that can be prepared using PHP's pg_prepare() function?

Comment: I'd imagine it's memory limited, though both the DB server's memory and the memory on the box running PHP would both be a factor as a prepared statement will create an object in PHP and a prepared statement on the database.

Comment: Though to be honest, if you're generating enough prepared statements for memory exhaustion to be an issue then your application's architecture probably needs a rethink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a numerical maximum number of `PREPARE`ed statements, there is a logical limit in the amount of RAM that a backend can allocate, however. As long as the `PREPARE` succeeds, the PostgreSQL backend will save the prepared statement until the connection drops, at which point it will clean up the `PREPARE`ed statements (or you could `DEALLOCATE` the `PREPARE`ed statement when you want to free up the memory).

All `PREPARED` statements are stored in a per-backend hash table. Memory allocation for the `PREPARE`ed statement is handled by the statement itself and is reassigned to the prepared statement cache. See `src/backend/commands/prepare.c` and `src/backend/utils/cache/plancache.c`:SaveCachedPlan() if you're curious about the details.

---

This information is current as of 2012-01-03 for PostgreSQL 9.1+ and may be different in the future when PostgreSQL supports a durable cache of `PREPARE`ed statements.

Comment: Excellent, that durable cache would be nice!